# Truncate (mass-delete) button not showing on all objects

Tags: custom-object, bulk-delete

I am getting the truncate button on some custom objects only. Is there any criteria for not having a truncate button on certain custom objects? Like, does having triggers/workflows on a custom object result in removal of the truncate button from that object?

Comment: Winter 13 guide has more info .Probably you may look at that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_object_trunc_overview.htm&language=en_US#TruncatingObjectsOverview

Here are the document and as per this if custom object is the master object of master-detail you cant truncate the object .

Comment: Thanks, it was the last point which was causing the problem:
•  Are referenced by another object through a lookup field or that are on the master side of a master-detail relationship
•  Are referenced in an analytic snapshot
•  Contain a geolocation custom field (beta)
•  Have a custom index or an external ID

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate custom objects in Salesforce using an internal feature called "Truncate". This feature is only available in classic.
Few things you need to keep in mind -
The truncate operation will fail if -

1. There is any reference to other objects through lookup or master-detail relationships.
2. The object is referenced in reporting snapshots.
3. The object is having a custom index or an external ID.
4. Have activated skinny tabled.
5. Truncate is going to delete the records permanently. So you will not be able to recover records from Recycle Bin.
6. A copy of the truncated object will be kept in the Deleted Objects list for 15-days.

Check out the blog post [here](https://www.sudipta-deb.in/2020/11/truncate-custom-objects-in-salesforce.html) and the video [here](https://youtu.be/jAq9fGFuD7U)

Comment: Please remember that the SFSE [promotion policy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) _requires_ you to disclose your affiliation to any outside properties clearly in your post. (Via [edit])